# Excel Conditional Formatting Percentage of Two cells

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

What I'm trying to do is format, say, cells A1 and B1 to be highlighted in red, when B1 is 80% or greater of what is in cell A1.

For example.

A1 = 10
B1 = 8

In this, I would want to have both cells highlighted in red, since B1 is 80% of A1.

If they were....

A1 = 10
B1 = 6

then they would simply stay the same without any formatting since it is only 60%.

Comment: Did you try to use excel "Conditional Formatting"? It has an option to do just what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Ribbon: Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format. In "Format values where this formula is true":

```
=($B$1/$A$1)>=0.8
```

You want to apply this formatting to A1 and B1, which can either be done in "manage rules" form box or simply by highlighting the cells you want it to apply to before setting the conditional format.